# Android media player not working as expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am very new to android just started with Android currently referring the below code from past 2 days, not able to fix the issue.

Code: 
https://github.com/quocnguyenvan/media-player-demo

Issue: Let's say we 4 Songs in the ListView when we click on the first song play it for some time and pause it without clicking on stop.
As soon as we click on the second song the first song starts playing we cannot play the second song unless we click on stop of the first song How to solve this issue.

The issue with code not able to figure out and fix it.I have referred many posts before posting on StackOverflow but could not make it, any suggestion or guidance is highly appreciated.

**Problematic code:**

```
// play music
    viewHolder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(flag){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music.getSong());
                flag = false;
            }
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        }
    });

    // stop
    viewHolder.ivStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!flag) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                flag = true;
            }
            viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I used for playing song you can try to sync with my steps to resolve the error.

```
  private void initMembers() {
    //initialize the members here
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    //media prepare
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            //media player prepared
            togglePlayPausePlayer();
        }
    });

    //media completion
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            //handle the media play completion
            handleOnCompletionLogic();
        }
    });
}
```

after that whenever I try to play the song. I call this method.

```
 public void playMusic(final MusicModel musicModel) {
    //here play the music with data in below
    try {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicModel.getUrl());
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
        showMessage(getString(R.string.error_unable_play));
    }
}
```

above resets the playing song and prepare the player for another song.
and OnPreparedListener it calls the togglePlayPausePlayer() which play and pause the song accordingly.

```
 private void togglePlayPausePlayer() {
        //here handle the logic for play and pause the player
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            setPlayAndPause(false);
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            setPlayAndPause(true);
        }
    }
```

The key is we initialize the player and set an onPrepareListener for the media player to get prepared and then play the song, which will check if it's playing then it will stop and else it will play.
hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

For on click on ListView you need to reset the media player, change the data source and start playing with new song.

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource("song you selected from ListView");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```